# Odd behavior of QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory (Qt5, python)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm experiencing an odd behavior of PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory function. When I call it, the dialog appears but when I select a directory, it appears again two more times and it is only at the third attempt to select the directory that it works. After this third attempt the program continues as expected. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Qt5 with Python 3.9.1 under windows 10.

The code is:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import mdat2cm_QtD # file created using QtDessing and pyuic5 filename.ui -o filename.py

def setCurrentDirectory(self) :
    #global self.workDirLabel, self.prefixComboBox, startFileNo, endFileNo, skipFileNo
    self.workDirLabel.setText(self.directory)
    return

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mdat2cm_QtD.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Add your custom code here
        try: 
            self.previousPath= open(os.path.expanduser('~')+"\\.mdat2cm_last").readlines()
            self.directory=self.previousPath[0]
            setCurrentDirectory(self)
        except:
            self.previousPath=[""]

        self.workDirButton.clicked.connect(self.on_workDirButton_clicked)

    def on_workDirButton_clicked(self):
        self.directory= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,'Select Working Directory',self.previousPath[0])
        try:
            with open(os.path.expanduser('~')+"\\.mdat2cm_last","w") as fff: 
                fff.write(self.directory)
        except:
            a=0
        return
```

I have also tried to add the QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog but the behavior did not change.

Comment: Advice: Use `pathlib.Path` to work with files and directories.

Comment: With that naming style, Qt automatically connects the function to the signal (which is also overloaded, so it's connected twice because there was no explicit slot). Either remove the connection, or rename the function.